# Refresh the main page when back button is pressed through navigation controller ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a main page  which when clicked takes me to another page  through navigation controller.I do some operations in  then press the main page navigation bar which takes me back to the main page but the problem is the main page doesn't get refreshed.No function are called not even Viewdidload.Is there a way to reload the view when i press the back button and refreshes the main page?

Comment: Use `viewWillAppear:`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can refresh your content in ViewDidAppear method, this method is being executed each time when view will appear on visible window.

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` would be better than `viewDidAppear:`. Otherwise the user may see the old data before the new data displays.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks alot didn't know that..I'll use viewWillAppear now

Comment: agreed with @rmaddy, If you have to refresh only then use viewWillAppear:, If you are doing refresh using web-services then apple recommended to use viewDidAppear: